# Docker beta for Windows and Windows Bash: path must be absolute

Tags: windows, bash, docker

When I try to run Docker container using windows bash, I've got this error:
`"path must be absolute"`, but using Power Shell everything works fine.

Is this a bug or I'm doing it wrong??

[image]

Comment: It appears that the error is reated to `-w` which specifies the workdir **inside** the container. Try use `-w //usr/app` (two slashes at beginning). This is just different behaviour of the shell environments.

Comment: I tried double slashes but it don't work. I posted the same thread on Docker forum and I've got hint that this is a problem with Cygwin.

Duplicated thread from docker forum with more info:
[https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-beta-for-windows-and-windows-bash-path-must-be-absolute/13355](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-beta-for-windows-and-windows-bash-path-must-be-absolute/13355)